# Pandas broadcasting

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following table:

```
Time    A    B    (A & B)   (A | B)    t1     t2
1Mon    T    T       T         T      1Mon  
1Tue    T    F       F         T
1Wed    F    T       F         T
1Thu    F    F       F         F             1Thu
1Fri    T    T       T         T      1Fri   
1Sat    T    T       T         T      1Sat
1Sun    F    F       F         F             1Sun
2Mon    F    F       F         F             2Mon
```

The conditions are as follows:

```
df['t1'] = df['Time'][df['(A & B)' == 'T']
df['t2'] = df['Time'][df['(A | B)' == 'F']
```

Is there a way to extract a pair of (T1, T2) using broadcasting / vectorization, such that:

- T1 is the earliest instance of t1 after a t2
- T2 is the earliest instance of t2 after t1

Which for the table above would return (1Mon, 1Thu) and (1Fri, 1Sun)..

I know the logic is somewhat recursive and can be achieved by looping through the dataframe. Just wanted to figure out if there's some magic by shifting the columns that can achieve too.

Edited some error

Comment: Wouldn't it be  `(1Mon, 1Thu)` and `(1Fri, 1Sun)` since `1Sun` occurs earlier than `2Mon` and it is the first element in the `t2` column that occurs after `1Fri` ? Also your conditions for what ends up in the `t1` and `t2` columns aren't consistent with what you are showing in your table.

Comment: You're right @bunji, my bad. Edited to the correct format now (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how generalizable this solution is, but since your `t1` and `t2` columns will always be distinct (i.e. `A&B != ~(A|B)` for any values of A and B) you can do something like this:

Start with your dataframe:

```
df

   Time  A  B (A & B) (A | B)    t1    t2
0  1Mon  T  T       T       T  1Mon   NaN
1  1Tue  T  F       F       T   NaN   NaN
2  1Wed  F  T       F       T   NaN   NaN
3  1Thu  F  F       F       F   NaN  1Thu
4  1Fri  T  T       T       T  1Fri   NaN
5  1Sat  T  T       T       T  1Sat   NaN
6  1Sun  F  F       F       F   NaN  1Sun
7  2Mon  F  F       F       F   NaN  2Mon
```

extract the relevant columns:

```
df2 = df[['t1', 't2']]
```

remove the rows that have all `NaN` values:

```
df2 = df2.dropna(how='all')
```

find the rows in `t1` that directly follow a non-null row (we don't want to keep these rows because they will never be the earliest instance of a `t1` after a `t2`):

```
useless_t1s = (df2.t1.shift().notnull() & df2.t1.notnull())
```

find the same for `t2`:

```
useless_t2s = (df2.t2.shift().notnull() & df2.t2.notnull())
```

now take only the useful rows from df2:

```
df2 = df2[~useless_t1s & ~useless_t2s]
```

We now have a table that only contains the rows that contain the cells that you are interested in:

```
df2

     t1    t2
0  1Mon   NaN
3   NaN  1Thu
4  1Fri   NaN
6   NaN  1Sun
```

Drop the null rows for each column and zip the results together to get your result:

```
result = zip(df2.t1.dropna(), df2.t2.dropna())

result

[('1Mon', '1Thu'), ('1Fri', '1Sun')]
```

Comment: Wow this is a little hard to wrap my head around @bunji. Let me try (:

Comment: @Yeile let me know which parts you're finding tricky and I'll be happy to add a more detailed explanation.